# Xcode fails to generate Adhoc IPA

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

Everything was working as expected but I've recently updated Xcode to 7.1.1 and it stopped to build IPA files in Adhoc.

After successfully archiving I click the Export option -> Save for Ad Hoc Deployment -> select my development team -> hit Next with "Export one app for all compatible devices" option -> Next (with Rebuild from bitcode checked). The error I get is this:

[image]

Comment: Ad hoc build was fixed in 7.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only workaround I found was to uncheck the "bitcode" option then everything went normal.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing this error on Xcode 7.2 myself and apparently the [Xcode 7.3 Beta](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.3_beta/Xcode_7.3_beta_Release_Notes.pdf) lists this as a known issue as well.

What I'm **really** interested in is a workaround for archives generated from Xcode Server.